# Ionic 3 - Runtime Error Cannot read property 'scrollToTop' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic3

I'm working on a project in Ionic 3. There are different menus. On selecting a menu I'm just publishing an event and changing the value of array on the page. Everything is working fine, but when the data of the page changes the scroll bar remains at the previous position. I want that everytime I select an item from menu the the page should be scrolled to top.

For this I'm using this-

The event is being published on selecting a menu item. The code is writtent at app.component.ts

```
onSelectCourse(slug){
    const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Loading Articles'
    });
    loading.present();
    if(slug == 'all'){
        this.postsProvider.listPosts(1)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.events.publish('posts:listed', data);
            loading.dismiss();
            this.menuCtrl.close();
        });
    }
    else{
        this.postsProvider.listPostsByCategory(slug, 1)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.events.publish('posts:listed', data);
            loading.dismiss();
            this.menuCtrl.close();
        });
    }
}
```

Subscribing the event at HomePage (home.ts)-

```
export class HomePage {
    posts: any = [];
    pages: number;
    page: number;
    category: string;
    @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
    constructor(
                private events: Events,
                private postsProvider: PostsProvider,
                private changeRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.events.subscribe('posts:listed', (data) => {
            this.posts = data.posts;
            this.pages = data.pages;
            this.page = 1;
            this.category = data.category;
            this.changeRef && this.changeRef.detectChanges();
            this.content.scrollToTop();
        });
    }
}
```

But on selecting an item, I'm getting this error

[image]

Comment: are you saying the list data changes in the subscribed event when "you select an item from menu" ? Asking because I had a similar issue..

Comment: Yes the list is being updated in the page, but scroll bar remains into the same position..

Comment: where or rather when is the event published?

Comment: the event is being published when I select a menu item. The code is writtent at app.component.ts.

Comment: Is homepage pushed before that? Otherwise, its view would not be generated yet

Comment: I have updated my complete code in the question..

Comment: As @Sampath mention, i think you should simulate your problem in stackblitz.com

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access it (i.e. `this.content.scrollToTop()`) inside the `constructor()` since `dom` is not being loaded yet.

You can use `ionViewDidEnter()` life cycle event here.

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
 events.subscribe('posts:listed', (data) => {
            ----
            ----
            this.content.scrollToTop();
        });
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.content`?

Comment: console.log(this.content); prints a long list of values - Content {_config: Config, _elementRef: ElementRef, _renderer: RendererAdapter, _componentName: "content", _mode: "ios", …}
color
:
(...)

Comment: Check whether is it has `scrollToTop()` method?

Comment: No at `runtime`?

Comment: Here is the documentation- https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#usage

Comment: Not in doc. When you run the app? See that in debug mode.

Comment: I am running the app in chrome, where can see the debug mode??